# Converting a String to small caps pseudoalphabet in Java

Tags: java, unicode, unicode-string

I found a website [which can convert any text to different obscure unicode font styles](http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=Test), e.g. `Small Caps pseudoalphabet`.

[image]

I'm interested in doing the same thing in Java code. The following [`HxD`](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd) screenshot shows the bytes of both text versions:
[image]

Is there any way to do the conversion in Java with built-in methods or a library? Preferrably the result will be another `String` object.

Comment: Not really. But it just takes some big look-up tables. There are certainly helpers that can run your character translation method over all characters in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a simple solution by translating the plain text alphabet to the Unicode "small caps" alphabet as follows:

```
private static final String[] ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
private static final String[] SMALL_CAPS_ALPHABET = "ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴩqʀꜱᴛᴜᴠᴡxyᴢ".split("");

private static String toSmallCaps(String text)
{
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    StringBuilder convertedBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (char textCharacter : text.toCharArray())
    {
        int index = 0;
        boolean successfullyTranslated = false;
        for (String alphabetLetter : ALPHABET)
        {
            if ((textCharacter + "").equals(alphabetLetter))
            {
                convertedBuilder.append(SMALL_CAPS_ALPHABET[index]);
                successfullyTranslated = true;
                break;
            }

            index++;
        }

        if (!successfullyTranslated)
        {
            convertedBuilder.append(textCharacter);
        }
    }

    return convertedBuilder.toString();
}
```

Usage:

```
String smallCaps = toSmallCaps("Hello StackOverflow!");
System.out.println(smallCaps);
```

Output:

```
ʜᴇʟʟᴏ ꜱᴛᴀᴄᴋᴏᴠᴇʀꜰʟᴏᴡ!
```

It's not the most elegant or extendable solution but maybe someone can suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the website you linked:

> What makes an alphabet "psuedo"?
>
> One or more of the letters transliterated has a different meaning or source than intended. In the non-bold version of Fraktur, for
>   example, several letters are "black letter" but most are "mathematical
>   fraktur". In the Faux Cyrillic and Faux Ethiopic, letters are selected
>   merely based on superficial similarities, rather than phonetic or
>   semantic similarities.

So there is no well-defined smallcaps transformation; rather, the author of the converter hand-picked codepoint mappings to give the desired effect.

In the case of small caps, this is probably because there is no small-caps version of `x` in unicode.

In order to recreate the same effect, you'll have to implement a codepoint conversion lookup table (which you could generate by, e.g., passing the whole alphabet to the transformer)

Answer (score 2):

The Unicode specification has an official, stable name for each and every codepoint.  You can take advantage of this by looking up “LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL *c*” using the method [Character.codePointOf(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#codePointOf%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public static String translate(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    Formatter smallCaps = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(len));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' && c != 'X') {
            smallCaps.format("%c",
                Character.codePointOf("LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL " + c));
        } else {
            smallCaps.format("%c", c);
        }
    }
    return smallCaps.toString();
}
```

I put `&& c != 'X'` in the test because there currently is no LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL X character, though [it has been proposed](http://unicode.org/L2/L2011/11208-n4068.pdf).

Note that some small capital codepoints may not be in Java’s internal copy of the Unicode character data table.  I found that I needed to use Java 12 or later to recognize them all.

Comment: Well, `Character.codePointOf()` is a `Java 9+` method and I still use `Java 8` but great suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59970204/276232) posted by @BullyWiiPlaza is a good one, but the code is pretty inefficient.

Here is an alternative implementation which will be much faster and uses less memory:

```
private static final char[] SMALL_CAPS_ALPHABET = "ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴩqʀꜱᴛᴜᴠᴡxyᴢ".toCharArray();

private static String toSmallCaps(String text)
{
    if(null == text) {
        return null;
    }
    int length = text.length();
    StringBuilder smallCaps = new StringBuilder(length);
    for(int i=0; i<length; ++i) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            smallCaps.append(SMALL_CAPS_ALPHABET[c - 'a']);
        } else {
            smallCaps.append(c);
        }
    }
    return smallCaps.toString();
}
```